# Get topics from new document based on trained LDA model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, lda

I've seen similar questions, but those are only works with PySpark.

I went through [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda) LDA example on Spark docs, but I did not find any way, how to use that model for detect topics (from the founded topics) in a brand new text or document.

E.g: If I use the subset of the reuters datase which means I have the following topics:

```
comp.graphics             rec.motorcycles     sci.crypt        sci.space           talk.religion.misc
comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware  rec.sport.baseball  sci.electronics  talk.politics.guns
rec.autos                 rec.sport.hockey    sci.med          talk.politics.misc
```

Then I have a model which is knows 13 topics and If I pass a brand new doc to the model about diabetes then I should get back the most suitable topics e.g: sci.med

Is it possible to achieve that? If yes, how should I do that?